# Evaluate $I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\left( a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x\right)^n} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to evaluate (using elementary methods if possible)   : (for $a>0,\ b>0$)

> $$
> I_n=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{( a\cos^2x+b\sin^2x)^n} \, dx,\quad \ n=1,2,3,\ldots
> $$
> I thought about using $u=\tan(x)$ or $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ but did not work. wolfram alpha evaluates the [indefinite integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(a%20Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%20%2B%20b%20Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2)%5En)  but not [definite integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F(a%20Cos%5Bx%5D%5E2%20%2B%20b%20Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2)%5En%20%20%7Bx,0,Pi%2F2%7D)???

Comment: you can use Feynman’s Trick

Comment: what is Feynman’s Trick???

Answer (score 13):

**Hint**:Use Feynman’s Trick: differentiate  the integral with respect to the parameters   $a$ and $b$, and it can be shown that:

$$\frac{\partial {{I}_{n}}}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial {{I}_{n}}}{\partial b}=-n{{I}_{n+1}}$$
This recursion can be re-written alternatively as:
$${{I}_{n}}=-\frac{1}{n-1}\left( \frac{\partial {{I}_{n-1}}}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial {{I}_{n-1}}}{\partial b} \right),\quad n=2,3,...$$
and notice that ${{I}_{1}}$ can be evaluated rather easily using $u=\tan \left( x \right)$ to get ${{I}_{1}}=\frac{\pi }{2\sqrt{ab}}$.

Comment: Is it possible to use Feynman's Trick here $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cos(A \cos(t))}{a^2 \sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t}dt?$$

Comment: I am not sure, let me try

Comment: Thank you. If you can, let me know, so I'll post this as a new question.

Comment: assume $I\left( A \right)=\int_{0}^{\pi /2\;}{\frac{\cos \left( A\cos \left( t \right) \right)}{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\left( t \right)+{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\left( t \right)}dt}$

Comment: differentiate w.r.s to $A$   n times$${{I}^{\left( n \right)}}\left( A \right)=\int_{0}^{{\pi }/{2}\;}{\frac{{{\cos }^{n}}\left( t \right)\cos \left( {n\pi }/{2}\;+A\cos \left( t \right) \right)}{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\left( t \right)+{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\left( t \right)}dt}$$

Comment: Now \begin{align}
  & {{I}^{\left( n \right)}}\left( 0 \right)={{\left( -1 \right)}^{\frac{n}{2}}}\int_{0}^{\pi /2\;}{\frac{{{\cos }^{n}}\left( t \right)}{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\left( t \right)+{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\left( t \right)}dt,\quad if\quad n=0,2,4,...} \\ 
 & {{I}^{\left( n \right)}}\left( 0 \right)=0,\quad if\quad n=1,3,5,... \\ 
\end{align}$
$

Comment: if we assume that $I\left( A \right)$ has a Maclaurin series representation,then $$I\left( A \right)=\sum\nolimits_{m=0}^{\infty }{\frac{{{I}^{\left( 2m \right)}}\left( 0 \right)}{\left( 2m \right)!}{{A}^{2m}}}$$  where $${{I}^{\left( 2m \right)}}\left( 0 \right)={{\left( -1 \right)}^{m+1}}\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2}+m \right){}_{2}{{F}_{1}}(\frac{1}{2},1,1+m,1-\frac{{{a}^{2}}}{{{b}^{2}}})}{2{{b}^{2}}m!}$$

Comment: this is complicated,,,,, sorry ,,,,,, i tried my best

Comment: besides i am not sure if it is valid to assume that $I\left( A \right)$ has a Maclaurin series? any way if you are going to post a question about this, write this attempt, i would like to see other answers or corrections.

Comment: This is a nice answer. But unfortunately, this does not work for me. Apparently, this integral was solved in terms of elementary functions by an acquaintance of mine. I do not know how he did it. There is another version of this integral. Are you interested?

Comment: yes i am, tell me

Comment: Here the integral: $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1-a \cos^2x}{A \cos^2x+B\sin^2x} \mathrm e^{-\frac{a}{2}\cos^2x}.  $$ I am sure that this can be solved in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: i agree and  i will take my time

Comment: I will post a question about the first integral.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886810/evaluation-of-int-0-pi-2-frac-cos-left-a-cos-t-righta2

Comment: If you are interested. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180192/why-cant-mathematica-compute-this-integral-int-0-pi-2-frac1-a-cos2x) is a discussion about this second integral.

Answer (score 6):

Per geometric summation
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n\ge 1}I_n t^n=&
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{t^n}{(a \cos^2x+ b \sin^2x)^n}dx\\
=&\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{t}{a\cos^2x+ b\sin^2x-t}dx
=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{t}{\sqrt{(a-t )(b-t )}}\\
 =&\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{i+j+1=n} \frac{1}{a^{i+1/2} b^{j+1/2}} {2i\choose i}{2j\choose j} t^n
\end{align}
where $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-t}}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{2^{2k} a^{k+1/2}} {2k\choose k }t^k$ is applied in the last step. Thus
$$I_n= \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}\sqrt{ab}}\sum_{i+j+1=n} \frac{{2i\choose i}{2j\choose j}}{a^{i} b^{j}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You may just use the residue theorem. $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable via $x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x$, so it is safe to assume $c\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\frac{b}{a}\in(0,1)$ (since the case $a=b$ is trivial) and study
$$ I_n(a,b) = \frac{1}{a^n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{(\cos^2\theta+c\sin^2\theta)^n}\stackrel{\theta\mapsto\arctan u}{=}\frac{1}{a^n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1+u^2)\left(\frac{1+cu^2}{1+u^2}\right)^n}$$
which is
$$ \frac{1}{2a^n}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{(1+u^2)^{n-1}}{(1+cu^2)^{n}}\,du =\frac{\pi i}{a^n}\operatorname*{Res}_{u=i/\sqrt{c}}\frac{(1+u^2)^{n-1}}{(1+cu^2)^n}.$$
$u=\frac{i}{\sqrt{c}}$ is clearly a pole of order $n$ for $\frac{(1+u^2)^{n-1}}{(1+cu^2)^n}$, hence the RHS equals
$$\frac{\pi i}{(n-1)! a^n c^n}\lim_{u\to \frac{i}{\sqrt{c}}} \frac{d^{n-1}}{du^{n-1}}\frac{(1+u^2)^{n-1}}{\left(u+\frac{i}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^n}. $$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

For the antiderivative, Wolfram Alpha (and other CAS) return, for $$J_n(x)=(n-1)(a-b) I_n(x)$$s the messy expression
$$2^{n-1} \csc (2 x) \sqrt{\frac{(a-b) \sin ^2(x)}{a}} \sqrt{\frac{(b-a) \cos ^2(x)}{b}}$$ $$
   ((a-b) \cos (2 x)+a+b)^{1-n}$$ $$
   F_1\left(1-n;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};2-n;\frac{a+b+(a-b) \cos (2 x)}{2
   b},\frac{a+b+(a-b) \cos (2 x)}{2 a}\right)$$ where appears

The problem is that both $J_n\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ and $J_n\left(0\right)$ result in indeterminate forms and that the limits need to be worked.

These would be
$$J_n\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}} \sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a}}\, b^{1-n}\, \Gamma (2-n)}{2
  \, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)}\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-n;\frac{3}{2}-n;\frac{b}{a}\right)$$
$$J_n\left(0\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}} \sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a}} \,a^{1-n}\, \Gamma (2-n)}{2\,
   \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)}\, \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-n;\frac{3}{2}-n;\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

Have fun !

Comment: +1 thanks this is helpful

Comment: @user579627. You are welcome ! I wanted to explain why, having the antiderivative, may not correspond to the end of the work for the integral. Good example. Cheers.