# Is there any other way to solve this difficult integral $ \int \frac{1}{ (a^2 \cos ^2 x + b ^ 2 \sin ^2x) ^2} \ dx $

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$
 \int \frac{1}{ (a^2 \cos ^2 x + b ^ 2  \sin ^2x) ^2} \ dx
$$

So this is the question .

*The solution given in book is to divide numerator and denominator by $\cos ^4x$ and then substitute $\tan x = t$ in the resulting integrand.*

*Other way of doing this was to substitute $b \tan x = a \tan t$.*

So I was thinking is not there any other way to solve this as it seems to a *complicated* problem as the given methods are very lengthy while solving.

**Any simpler\shorter method anyone could think of ?**

Comment: I think there is none.

Comment: A more general case of your question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876586/evaluation-of-int-0-pi-2-frac1-left-a-cos2xb-sin2x-rightn)

Comment: @logo That is very different . also even that is not answered well .

Comment: Would it help at all to re-express the denominator as $\left((a^2-b^2)\cos^2x+b^2\right)^2$ via the identity $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$? You could clean it up a little more by letting $a^2-b^2=\alpha$ and $b^2=\beta$, so you're just left with $$\int\frac{1}{\left(\alpha \cos^2x+\beta\right)^2}\,dx$$
You can also plug it into [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com) and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
\begin{align} I(a,b)&=\int \frac{1}{ a^2\cos ^2 x + b^2 \sin ^2x}dx\\
&=\int \frac{d(\tan x)}{ a^2+b^2\tan ^2 x }
=\frac1{ab}\tan^{-1}\bigg({\frac ba}\tan x \bigg)
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{ (a^2\cos ^2 x + b^2 \sin ^2x)^2}dx
=  -\frac12\left(\frac{I’_a}a+\frac{I’_b}b\right)\\
=&\ \frac1{2ab}\left(\frac1{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}\right)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac ba\tan x \right)
+ \frac12\left(\frac1{a^2}-\frac1{b^2}\right)\frac{\tan x}{b^2\tan^2x+a^2}
\end{align}