# An integral and a mysterious recursive sequence

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

Today I tried to solve the integral
$$I_n= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\mathrm{dt}}{(a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t))^n} \quad \quad \quad \quad a,b > 0$$

After some dirty calculations, I obtained that
$$I_n = \frac{\pi}{2^n(n-1)!\sqrt{ab}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{C(n-1,k)}{a^kb^{n-1-k}}$$

where the $C(n,k)$ are defined for $n \geq 1$ and $0 \leq k \leq n$ and satisfy the "Pascal-like" recursive relation
$$C(n,k)=(2k-1) \times C(n-1,k-1)+(2n-2k-1) \times C(n-1,k) \quad \quad n\geq 2, \text{ } k \geq 1$$
with the initial conditions $$C(1,0)=C(1,1)=1 \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad C(n,0)=C(n,n)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!} \text{ for all } n$$

My question are :

- is that a "well-known" sequence of coefficients ? Do you know if they appear in some other problems ?
- are also these integrals well-known ? Do you maybe know an elegant way to solve them ?

In a summary, can you tell me anything you know about these integrals and this recursive sequence !

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :** As @ReneGy pointed out, this sequence is apparently registered is OEIS as A059366. But OEIS does not mention the recursive relation I gave... I am still taking anything you can tell me about this mysterious sequence and these integrals !

Comment: some solutions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2876586/evaluation-of-int-0-pi-2-frac1-left-a-cos2xb-sin2x-rightn?noredirect=1

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thanks for the link ! The given recursion formula is the one I used for my computation, but they don't mention the "closed" form in term of the coefficients $C(n,k)$, which is weird since the formula comes easily when you have the recursive relation.

Comment: Since you're after a source: this integral and its recurrence relation appear in page 182 of Companion to Concrete Mathematics: volume I by Z. A. Melzak.

Answer (score 7):

Now, the new triangular table for $C(n,k)$

| n\k | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 15 | 9 | 9 | 15 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 105 | 60 | 54 | 60 | 105 |  |  |
| 5 | 945 | 525 | 450 | 450 | 525 | 945 |  |
| 6 | 10395 | 5670 | 4725 | 4500 | 4725 | 5670 | 10395 |

This is [A059366](http://oeis.org/A059366) in the OEIS.
Apparently, these numbers were already found for the calculation of $$I_n= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\mathrm{dt}}{(a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t))^n} \quad \quad \quad \quad a,b > 0,$$see   *L. Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics, Reidel, 1974, pp. 166-167*.

We have:

$$  \sum_{n\ge 0}I_nx^n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{dt}\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{x^n}{(a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t))^n}= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathrm{dt}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t)}}$$
$$  \sum_{n\ge 0}I_nx^n= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t)}{a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t)-x}\mathrm{dt}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x}{a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t)-x}\mathrm{dt}$$
$$  \sum_{n\ge 0}I_nx^n=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x}{a-x + (b-x) \tan^2(t)}\mathrm{d\tan{t}}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x}{a-x + (b-x) t^2}\mathrm{dt}$$
$$  \sum_{n\ge 0}I_nx^n=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{x}{a-x}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 +  (\frac{\sqrt{b-x}}{\sqrt{a-x}}t)^2}\mathrm{dt}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{x}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1 +  t^2}\mathrm{dt}$$
$$  \sum_{n\ge 0}I_nx^n=\frac{\pi}{2}\big(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)}}\big)$$

then , for $n\gt 0$
$$I_n = \frac{\pi}{2} [x^{n}]\frac{x}{\sqrt{(a-x)(b-x)}}$$
but $$  \sum_{i\ge 0}{2i\choose i}\big(\frac{x}{a}\big)^i=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt{a-4x}}.$$

Then we have
$$I_n = \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}\sqrt{ab}} \sum_{i+j=n-1} \frac{{2i\choose i}}{a^i}\frac{{2j\choose j}}{b^j}.$$

By identification to the OP formula, this gives
$$C(n,k)=  \frac{n!}{2^n}{2k\choose k}{2(n-k)\choose n-k} $$

which is
$$C(n,k)=  (-2)^n{n\choose k}{-\frac{1}{2}\choose k} {-\frac{1}{2}\choose n-k}$$ which is given in the above OEIS link (with a typo).

It should be not so difficult to verify that these closed formulae for $C(n,k)$ do satisfy the above recursion.

Comment: Great ! But I am a little bit startled : neither the OEIS page nor the Comtet book mention the recursive relation for the $C(n,k)$... They mention another recursive, but far more complicated, relation...

Comment: Great idea, the generating function ! I will have a look to this method. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Note that
\begin{align}
& \left( \frac{(b-a)\sin t\cos t}{(a \cos^2 t+ b \sin^2 t)^{n-1}} \right)’\\
= & -\frac{{2(n-1)ab}}{(a \cos^2 t+ b \sin^2 t)^n}
 + \frac{{(2n-3)(a+b)}}{(a \cos^2 t+ b \sin^2 t)^{n-1}}
- \frac{{2(n-2)}}{(a \cos^2 t+ b \sin^2 t)^{n-2}}
\end{align}
Integrate both sides to establish
$$(n-1)I_n =  (n-\frac32)\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right)I_{n-1}-\frac{n-2}{ab}I_{n-2}
$$
with $I_1 =\frac\pi{2\sqrt{ab}}$. Then

\begin{align}
& I_2 = \frac12 I_1\left(\frac1a+\frac1b\right) \\
& I_3 = \frac18I_1\left(\frac3{a^2}+\frac2{ab}+\frac3{b^2}\right)\\
&\>\cdots\\
& I_n = I_1
\left(\frac{c_{n,0}}{a^{n-1} }+ \frac{c_{n,1}}{a^{n-2}b} + \cdots + \frac{c_{n,n-1}}{b^{n-1} }\right)
\end{align}
where the coefficients satisfy the recursive relationship $c_{n,0}=c_{n,n-1}=\frac{(2n-3)!!}{(2n-2)!!}$
$$c_{n,k} = \frac{2n-3}{2(n-1)}(c_{n-1,k} +c_{n-1,k-1})
 - \frac{n-2}{n-1}c_{n-2,k-1}$$

Comment: Thanks, this is a clever way of solving this integral +1 ! Actually, this is the recursive relation between the coefficients that puzzles me the most. The relation I found appears nowhere and is much simpler than the ones I read... Could you maybe detail which relation you could find with your method ? And do you know if that sequence appears in some other context ? Thanks again !

Comment: Thanks for the precision ! But again, your recursive formula is quite more complicated than the one I found... Maybe I have been mistaken, but I don't think so... If you have time, could you please check that your coefficients satisfy the relation I wrote in my question ? Thanks !

Comment: @Henry - I could not quite figure out your recursion. Take $C(2,0)=-C(1,-1)+3C(1,0)$, which does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I should have precised that the recursion formula works for $n \geq 2$ and $k\geq 1$. That's why I gave as initial conditions the values of the $C(n,0)$'s. This is exactly the kind of relation you have for binomials, where the $(n,k)$-th coefficient is related to the $(n-1,k-1)$-th and the $(n-1,k)$-th. Does it make more sense ?

Comment: @Henry - Makes sense. I verified that both recursive formuli produce the same coefficients up to $n=5$. So, they must be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

There is an antiderivative for
$$J_n= \int \frac{\mathrm{dt}}{\big[a \cos^2(t)+ b \sin^2(t)\big]^n} $$
(have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B%28a+Cos%5Bt%5D%5E2+%2B+b+Sin%5Bt%5D%5E2%29%5E-n%2Ct%5D)) in terms of the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

Using the integration bounds,
$$I_n=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{1-\frac{a}{b}} \sqrt{1-\frac{b}{a}} \,\Gamma (2-n) }{2 (n-1) (a-b) (ab)^n \,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{2}-n\right)} \,A$$ where
$$A=a^n b\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-n;\frac{3-2n}{2};\frac{b}{a}\right)+a b^n \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1-n;\frac{3-2n}{2};\frac{a}{b}\right)$$ where appears the gaussian hypergeometric function.

Comment: Great ! I am a little bit relieved that the integral cannot be solved explicitely in term of usual functions... I was afraid of having missed something simple. Do you know if these integrals appear in some context ? And something about the recursive sequence that intrigues me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Henry. I am also stuck with the recursive sequence.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time ! Let's wait for - hopefully - other answers...

Answer (score 2):

Start with

$$J_n(p)=\frac2\pi \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{{dt}}{(p \cos^2t+ \sin^2t)^n}$$

$$J_{n+1}(p)=J_n(p)+\frac{p-1}n J_n’(p)\tag 1
$$
With $J_1(p)= \frac1{p^{1/2}} $
\begin{align}
& J_2 (p)=\frac12\left(\frac1{p^{1/2}}+\frac1{p^{3/2}}\right)\\
& J_3 (p)= \frac18\left(\frac3{p^{1/2}}+\frac2{p^{3/2}}+\frac3{p^{5/2}}\right)\\
& J_4 (p)= \frac1{16}\left(\frac5{p^{1/2}}+\frac3{p^{3/2}}+\frac3{p^{5/2}}+\frac5{p^{7/2}}\right)\\
& \cdots\>\cdots\\
& J_{n}(p) = \frac{c_{n-1,0} }{p^{1/2}}+ \frac{c_{n-1,1} }{p^{3/2}}+\cdots + \frac{c_{n-1,n-1} }{p^{(2n-1)/2}}\\
& J_{n+1}(p) = \frac{c_{n,0} }{p^{1/2}}+ \frac{c_{n,1} }{p^{3/2}}+\cdots + \frac{c_{n,n-1} }{p^{(2n-1)/2}}+\frac{c_{n,n} }{p^{(2n+1)/2}}
\end{align}

with the coefficients satisfying the recursion $c_{0,0}=1,\>c_{n,0}= \frac{2n-1}{2n}c_{n-1,0}$
$$c_{n,k}=\frac{k-n-1}kc_{n,k-1} +\frac nk c_{n-1,k-1}, \>\>\>\>\>k\ne 0$$

Then

\begin{align}
I_{n+1} &= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{{dt}}{(a \cos^2t+ b\sin^2t)^{n+1}}
=\frac\pi2 \frac1{b^{n+1}} J_{n+1}\left(\frac ab \right)\\
&=  \frac\pi2\left(\frac{c_{n,0} }{a^{1/2}b^{(2n+1)/2}}+ \frac{c_{n,1} }{a^{3/2}b^{(2n-1)/2}}+\cdots + \frac{c_{n,n} }{a^{(2n+1)/2}b^{1/2}}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! Yes, this is basically the method I used first, except that I udes partial differentiation w.r.t. $a$ and $b$, rather than using a single variable as you did here (which is indeed a good way to simplify a little bit the calculation !)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but too long for comment: here is a triangular table for $C(n,k)$

| n\k | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 15 |  |  |  |
| 4 | 0 | 15 | 27 | 45 | 105 |  |  |
| 5 | 0 | 105 | 180 | 270 | 420 | 945 |  |
| 6 | 0 | 945 | 1575 | 2250 | 3150 | 4725 | 10395 |

It does not seem to be in the OEIS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually, I should have precised that the initial values of $C(n,k)$ are given by $C(1,0)=C(1,1)=1$. So the coefficients are a little bit different... if I have not been mistaken in my calculations ! I will edit my question to make the first values of $C(n,k)$ appear.

Comment: In this case, I think you should also specify $C(n,0)$ for $n\gt1$ as an additional initial condition.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Actually, they must satisfy $C(n,0)=C(n,n)=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$, I add this to the question ! Thanks for your comment !